# JavaScript, Canvas : change filename when saving in local

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I want to save canvas as image.jpeg/jpg/png in local with a filename and extension.
I used the download attribute as following :

```
<a download="change_this.jpg" id="saveImage"><img src="image/save.png" alt=""></a>
```

By setting default filename and extension, I am able to download canvas as image. So I tried something that seems logic to me but nothing's working :

```
saveImage.addEventListener('click', function(){

    var filename = prompt('Filename with extension (png/jpeg/jpg) : ');
    var img_name = filename.substr(0, filename.indexOf("."));
    var extension = filename.substr(filename.indexOf(".") + 1);

    if(filename !== null){

        if(extension == "png"){
            save(img_name, extension);
        }else if(extension == "jpg" || extension == "jpeg"){
            save(img_name, extension);
        }
    }


}, false);
```

And the save function :

```
function save(img_name, extension){

var req_type = 'image/' + extension;
var image = canvas.toDataURL(req_type);
image.download = img_name + "." + extension;
this.href = image;}
```

And of course I correctly selected  and  element with ID : the are globals.

Maybe It's not working because of the click on 1 element doing 2 things at once.

Thanks for your helpe!

Comment: `image` is a String, and setting a `.download` property to it won't do any good. And `this` is the window in that context. You have to catch back your anschor element, and set **its*  download property. (Ps: Voting to close as "typo, won't help future readers")

Comment: How can i do that? Catching the <a> when calling save()

Comment: Seems you already have a variable called `saveImage` which is holding it, so maybe you can reuse it (can't see the closure from these parts of code)

Comment: Worked perfectly !! Thants @Kaiido !